# Reduce azure maintenance cost

Tags: azure

Currently we have 2 environments in Azure
1.staging environment
2.live/production environment

both environment are in separate accounts
is it advisable to have both environments in one account and have them share the same resource group? will that reduce the maintenance cost? 
what are the pros and cons of having 2 environments share the same resource group

Any tips and tricks on optimizing azure?

Any advise is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The answer depends on several details (what kind of ressources and how many, are you using continous deployment and so on). There are plenty of solutions for different resource types like slots for web apps. Also you should not mix up 2 questions in 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*both environment are in separate accounts is it advisable to have both environments in one account and have them share the same resource group?*

Yes. If your staging environment is not used frequently, you can turn off the "Always On" setting to decrease memory usage.

And if your application uses a database, you may need to configure a different one than the production . If you are using SQL Service, you can use S0 (10 DTUs) instance which does not cost you much.

*will that reduce the maintenance cost?*

Instead of using two different resource groups, you'll start using one. That should reduce your costs.

*what are the pros and cons of having 2 environments share the same resource group*

Pros:

- Less cost

Cons:

- If the app on staging consumes so much resource, the resource group may be affected negatively. If scale out option is on, capacity may be increased automatically which can increase the costs.

Comment: Hi, What is an s10 instance?

Comment: What if... we have 3 clients each client has a staging environment in separate user groups. Can I create one user group? and have one SQL instance with 3 databases? what if one database consumes more memory than the other 2?

Comment: It's not S10. I2ve corrected it to S0 which has a capacity of 10 DTUs. You can see different types at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/.

Comment: Each database has its own capacity limit if you go with the option of Single Database. You can define capacity limits for each database you have. For example, a frequently accessed database may have 100 DTUs whereas a less accessed database (like a staging database) may have 10 DTUs. They don't affect each other in terms of resource utilization. But if you prefer to use an elastic pool in which your databases exist, you manage the collective capacity of them. Please look at the link in my earlier comment. There you'll find explanations of each option.

Answer (score 1):

[Azure Cost Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management/overview) lets you view and optimize cloud spending in general. This is a general answer to a general question.